# Sending Map of Map(POJO) from Spring Boot to Reactjs

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I am not able to figure out how to Send Map of Map from Java(Spring Boot) to ReactJS as Map of Map only.(GET API)
For example, I have a Map of Map, Map<Integer,Pair<Map<String,String>,String>> that I need to send to ReactJS in this format.
Can I somehow retain this format?
I have tried various things, also played around Jackson API but was not able to land on anything.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a JSON equivalent example?